# Hover text on dropdown - jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to hover text in dropdown, when the text length is more than width of the dropdown?

```
 <Select style="width:10px">
  <option>Less than 10 px </option>
  <option> More than 10 px </option>
 </Select>
```

I want the display text "more than 10 Px" on hover, from my above example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a "title" tag:

```
<option title="More than 10 px"> More than 10 px </option>
```

Comment: What if when dropdown is populated dynamically?

Comment: Then add in your for loop the attribute title.

Comment: Even if it's populated dynamically, just add the "title" tag to the option, such as $("select").append("<option title='hello'></option>") etc